# Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[model.Entity2#17046]. ignore entities2 that are not related to the entity1

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

i'm using spring boot for a rest project and i'm using postman for json response.
I have a dirty database she has entitis2 that are no connected to a entitis1.
for example in db i have entity1 table with: id=1 and entity2=mouse but in entity2 table not exists entity2=mouse
I want to ignore entities2 that are not related to the entity1.

Eentitis1Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getAll",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<entitis1 > getAll() {

    return (List<entitis1 >) entitis1Repository.findAll();
}
```

Entitis1 :

```
@Id
private long id;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,optional = false)
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Entity2 entity2 ;
```